# Com Exception when try to find iterator

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have a `C#` console application.
It uses Excel interop to open various `xlsm` files and run some macros.
Once the macros have run it closes down Excel and releases the `COM` objects in the finally I have the following:

```
try
{

  foreach(Excel.Workbook wkb in wbs)  //<<<<<<<<line 148
  {
    if(wkb.Name != "HelperRoutinesNetwork.xlsm")
    {
      wkb.Close(false,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
      if(wkb != null)
      {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wkb);
      }
    }
  }

  if(wb != null)
  {
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wb);
  }


  if(wbs != null)
  {
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wbs);
  }


  if(xlApp != null)
  {
    xlApp.Quit();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);
  }

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION_tryingToReleaseComObjs: {0}",ex.ToString());
}
```

It is catching an exception on the `foreach` line 148 (marked above):

[image]

What could be the causes of this and how do I avoid it?

Comment: try to run the Visual Studio as Administrator (pin it to the task bar --> right-click --> Run as Administrator). It might be realted to Administrator privileges.

Comment: I am not sure how much this will help you but take a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99271/c-sharp-com-office-automation-rpc-e-sys-call-failed

Comment: Very weird, what happens if you take the count and loop with a `for` loop instead of the `foreach`?

Comment: How are you populating the object `wbs`? Have you been able to access them from other methods and does it only fail during this foreach loop?

Comment: @Draken this line of code with the foreach is executed 40 or 50 times a day without error. The error only seems to occur when running one particular xlsm macro, and even then it does not always throw an exception.